# add string to end of line in shape object

Tags: vba, ms-word

I search in shape object specific string and replace with another string after the change i want to add to end line one more string.

To the first part (the search string and replace) i used:

```
set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(indexShape).TextFrame.TextRange
With oShape.find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = i_wordToFind
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = i_ValueResponsible
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
End With
```

How can i add string to end of line that i find the string?

Thank,
Tal

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you although it replaces `i_WordToFind` only in its first occurrence.

```
Private Sub InputTal()

    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(indexShape)
    Set Rng = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    Rng.Find.Execute FindText:=i_WordToFind, Forward:=True
    If Rng.Find.Found Then
        With Rng
            .Text = i_ValueResponsible
            .MoveUntil Cset:=Chr(11) & Chr(13)
            .Text = " " & i_ValueResponsible
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```